# Convert to JSON without using split in Python Scrapy

Tags: python

```
dict = {clientId: "300",id: "new",ctime: "6/3/2022",mtime: "6/3/2022"}
```

I try this but its not working:

```
JO = json.joads(dict)

clientId = JO['clientId']

id = JO['id']
```

*TypeError: string indices must be integers*

i want data like that:

```
clientId = 300
id = new
ctime = 6/3/2022
mtime = 6/3/2022
```

Comment: Please use code tags, here is a link that might help improve your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

According to me, you shoudn't assign `dict` as variable, even its works but shouldn't assign. second your passing`clientId` variable as key, which you haven't defined so I took as string.

In case of your existing code update this:

```
d = json.dumps(dict)
JO = json.loads(d)

clientId = JO['clientId']
clientId
```

Or you can also try this without Json.

```
Dict = {'clientId': "300",'id': "new",'ctime': "6/3/2022",'mtime': "6/3/2022"}

clientId = Dict['clientId']
id = Dict['id']
ctime = Dict['ctime']
mtime = Dict['mtime']
```